# How to place divs on a webpage in rows of three with bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I place six divs on a web page in two rows and three columns? 
I tried the follwoing code with bootstarp but the divs do not appear is a row rather after each other in a column

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span4" id="chart_1"></div>
  <div class="span4" id="chart_2"></div>
  <div class="span4" id="chart_3"></div>
</div>
```

**fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/r2qepmk0/3/**

**Edit**
When I add col-xs-4 class to my divs my d3 charts stop rendering is there another possible solution to this?

Comment: you may want to open a new question for just your d3 issue. bootstrap adds floats and widths that could interfere with d3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One suggestion first, wrap your layout in a bootstrap container class. By default the row class has `-15px` left and right margins, while the container class has `15px` of left and right padding. They're meant to work in tandem and bring your content flush to the outside of the container.

Secondly, use the `col-` syntax.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4" id="chart_1">23</div>
        <div class="col-xs-4" id="chart_2">45</div>
        <div class="col-xs-4" id="chart_3">34</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4" id="chart_3">34</div>
        <div class="col-xs-4" id="chart_1">23</div>
        <div class="col-xs-4" id="chart_2">45</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0vu83eru/1/

Answer (score 1):

Use `class="col-xs-4"` see fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/r2qepmk0/1/

And what you want about w3fools, but this link explains it well http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_basic.asp

Answer (score 1):

You are using `bootstrap 2.*` syntax while your fiddle has `bootstrap 3.3.5` css included. Change your column syntax to this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4" id="chart_1">23</div>
  <div class="col-xs-4" id="chart_2">45</div>
  <div class="col-xs-4" id="chart_3">34</div>
</div>
```

And it should work fine for you. Please refer to the documentation for the current version of [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/).

And your updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r2qepmk0/2/)

Comment: nb, the bootstrap documentation is god awful. half the time you're better off adding [one of the bootstrap classes](https://gist.github.com/mrcybermac/9175466) while debugging and seeing what rules are applied.

Comment: The problem is that when I use col-xs-4 my d3 charts wont render

Comment: Don't `d3` charts need a fixed height to render?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to wrap your `<div>`s in a `<div class="col-xs-4">` and everything should be good.

Currently, the bootstrap classes are interfering with the styles applied by the D3 js, which creates the result seen in your fiddle. You should also remove the `class="span4"` because, as already mentioned, that is bootstrap  version 2.x and you are using 3.x.

Answer (score -1):

You can put six divs in two rows and three columns by doing something like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span4" id="chart_1"></div>
  <div class="span4" id="chart_2"></div>
  <div class="span4" id="chart_3"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="span4" id="chart_4"></div>
  <div class="span4" id="chart_5"></div>
  <div class="span4" id="chart_6"></div>
</div>
```

Remember that you can use the class `row-fluid` to get more flexibility in your web page

Comment: That's the wrong syntax for `bootstrap 3.*`. `span`s were used in `bootstrap 2.*` but have since been deprecated in favor of `col` classes.